# MIPS reading stdinput and writing it to console

Tags: assembly, mips, stdin

I've just started to learn Mips and here is my first try to write something.

```
    .data
        testi:  .asciiz "give me an input"
        input:  .space 5
    .text
        li $v0,4
        la $a0,testi
        syscall
        li $v0,8
        la $a0,input
        syscall
        li $v0,4
        syscall
        li $v0,10
        syscall
```

I've expected that it writes "give me an input" and waiting me to write something and after that it stores it into input and write to console finally.Unfortunately, It did not happend. I got an error says that:
 *"instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400014 [0x00400014] [0x0000000] jal 0x0000000000[main]" ;188;jal main*

Is there anyone to help me to figure it out ? THanks in advance.

Note : While loading the file that I wrote this code above, I dont get any error. It comes out when I click run button

**EDIT**
Thanks to @PeterT, I solved my problem.However I've a second question.Again I though that writing `input:  .space 5` would give me a space with size of 5 byte and I shouldnt exceed this limit. However, altough I give *thisIsAnTestInput*(more than 5 character) to input and want to write it into console, it gives me exactly the same input(I've expected just get *thisI)*. I want to know where I'm wrong.

Comment: pretty sure that it can't find the label `main:` (entrypoint for the executable). So just write a line that contains `main:` after `.text`

Comment: @PeterT thanks for reply. I've edited my question. Could you look again ?

Comment: it doesn't automagically figure out the size of the buffer, you're overflowing it. You can pass the buffer size as a second parameter in `$a1`. So add a `li $a1 5` before making the second syscall (btw. it may cut off 1 character to write the \0 string terminator).

Comment: @PeterT Let me correct If I get wrong. Writing more than 5 byte in input is not cool, since I assign its size for 5 bytes however,If I exceed it, mips takes care ?

Comment: nope, some raw toy-mips implementation may just ignore the buffer overflow but if you were to write this in an actual operating system you'd probably get segmentation fault/access violation error or whatever OS equivalent. If you're lucky it might work fine for a few bytes but after a while you'll produce weird results by trying to write into memory that you didn't allocate or overwriting other memory or even code (won't be allowed in an actual OS).

Comment: @PeterT thanks for again. So If I have a stdinput whose size at most 100 , writing `var1:  .space 101  li $v0,8 li $a1,101` will be enough I think ?

Comment: @PeterT I'm so greatful to your replys. Thanks a lot